# How to view this pseudocode in math symbols?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to find some intuition on why the closed path integral of a complex differentiable function is $0$ and I ended up with this:

A complex number $z=z_1+iz_2$ is basically a vector $z=(z_1,z_2)$. If we define the cross product $(z_1,z_2) \times (w_1,w_2) = -z_1w_2 + z_2w_1$, then we can write the multiplication of two complex numbers as $z$ and $w$ as $ z\circ w = z \cdot \overline{w} + i z \times \overline{w} $.

Now, why is the closed path integral of a differentiable function equal to $0$ ? Because its divergence and curl are zero.

The fact that the divergence and the curl are zero is exactly the Cauchy-Riemann equation which is $\partial _x f = -i \partial _y f,$ or $( \partial _x + i \partial _y ) \circ f = 0 $. If we define $\nabla := ( \partial _x + i \partial _y ),$ then our equation is $\nabla \circ f = 0 ,$ or $\nabla \cdot \overline{f} + i \nabla \times \overline{f} = 0.$

Which implies $ \nabla \cdot \overline{f} =0$ and $ \nabla \times \overline{f} = 0.$

A closed path integral is $\oint _\gamma f \circ dz.$ By Stoke's theorem $ \oint _\gamma f \circ dz = \oint _\gamma f \cdot dz + i \oint _\gamma f \times dz = \int _\Omega \nabla \cdot f dA + i \int _\Omega \nabla \times f dA = \int _\Omega \nabla \circ f dA$.

But by the Cauchy Riemann equation $\int _\Omega \nabla \circ f dA = 0.$

Is there anything more to say about this? Is there more I can learn? I found it really interesting to see how the Cauchy Riemann equation is exactly $\nabla \circ f = 0 $ and how the divergence and curl are encoded with $\nabla \circ.$

Source: https://www.google.co.kr/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/math/comments/6cy2xw/c_vs_r2_relation_of_complex_derivative_and_its/

Comment: On the right-had side of the reddit page, there is a section called "Using LaTeX" that tells you how to render the code as readable math.

Comment: It is well that you have found a document that explains this connexion. I strongly advise you the reading of the two books of Peter Henrici "Applied and Computational Complex Analysis": they are partly accessible as Google books.

Comment: I do not agree to close such an interesting text. There are so many people that don't show any work !

Comment: Here, the formulas have to be enclosed between dollar signs and not between $[;$ and $;]$. I have corrected your text.

Comment: Last thing: I don't understand your title.